# Blood pressure in various blood vessels and heart

Tags: physiology, homework

What are the typical systolic and diastolic blood pressure in arteries,capillaries, veins and the heart?

I know it must be highest in the arteries. arteries>capillaries>veins

Arteries: 120-80mmHg (systolic - diastolic). I also found mean values for capillaries (30mmHg) and veins (10mmHg) but not able to find systolic and diastolic pressure specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blood vessels have "[compliance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compliance_(physiology))": that is, they are stretchy. Mathematically, this is very similar to capacitance in electricity.

The further from the heart you go into the vascular tree, the more the oscillations are dampened and the less it makes sense to think of systolic and diastolic pressures. In the capillaries and veins, blood flow and pressure is more or less constant rather than oscillatory (except in the most proximal veins where the motion of the heart again adds some pulsatile influences).

Therefore, for those vessels, you can just stick to mean values for pressure, the oscillations around those values are small.

See another Q&A: [Why do people perceive blood pressure as the force that moves the blood forwards (see details)?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/54740/why-do-people-perceive-blood-pressure-as-the-force-that-moves-the-blood-forwards) that has a diagram showing the dampening of oscillations in pressure.

Comment: thanks a lot! and what can be said about the pressure in heart? I thought 0 during diastole and around 120mmHg during systole ( I thought during systole it is similar to that of arteries )